# Selecting 'li' of different 'ul' - jQuery

Tags: jquery

My html is as Follows

```
<ul id="ul1">
  <li>
   content1
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="ul2">
  <li>
   content2
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="ul3">
  <li>
   content3
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**

I need the content of these li's in array How can i do that in jQuery

```
array['ul1']='content1'
array['ul2']='content3'
```

Comment: Please post the desired array structure as you wrote in a comment below you need the information of the containing ul as well...

Comment: Arrays in javascript can't have string keys. What you need called "object" or "hash".

Comment: @Pozadi How to do if it is a hash??

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to write as below in jQuery

```
var myarray=new Array();
$("li").each(function() 
            {      
       var text = $(this).text();//you can also write html() function also...    
       var parentUI = $(this).parent('ul').attr("id"); 
       myarray.push(parentUI  + ',' + text ); 
  });
```

this means you just need to write out [Element Selector (“element”)](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) for this structure which is given in question

Comment: "I need the content of these li's"

Comment: But i need to know which ul they come from too

Answer (score 5):

Here's a one-liner for you. It will give you an array like this `["content1", "content2", "content3"]`

```
$('li').map(function () { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var arr = [];
$('li').each(function(index) {
  arr.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try This:

```
textArray = [];
i = 0

$("li").each(function() {
   textArray[i] = $(this).text();
   i++;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this code is what you looking for:

```
var result = {};
$("li").each(function() {
  result[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).text();
})
```